# How to create script to deploy asp.net application direct from clearcase?

Tags: asp.net, build-script, clearcase-remote-client

I am trying to write a script to deploy asp.net application from Clear Case. I am using Clear Case Remote Client.

How will i start? what is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCRC is for accessing code from a "web" ClearCase snapshot view.
Being a light ClearCase installation, you:

- won't have all the `cleartool` command which would allow to detect new content (new versions on files) to be updated
- won't have the easy integration you could have with TeamCity, or Jenkins, or Hudson, ... since they all rely on a `cleartool` command.
  TeamCity, for instance, has still a [pending ticket on CCRC support](http://teamsys.intellij.net/issue/TW-9798).

For you, since you don't want/need to use those schedulers anyway, you can start by using the **[CCRC CLI](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929)** (`rcleartool`) in order to:

- update your ccweb view
- check if the update has gotten any new versions
- deploy your app if it has gotten anything new.

```
rcleartool update [-username user-name][-ser/ver server-url][-pas/sword user-password]
                  [-print] [-ove/rwrite | -nove/rwrite | -ren/ame]
                  [pname ...]
```

Jenkins currently follows a similar path to *plan* for CCRC support: [ticket 5192](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5192):
(and neither Jenkins nor Hudson support CCRC yet)

> I'm thinking about which is better the calling of `rcleartool` as external tool, or develop a teamapi (or as they call now cmapi) based pure java extension.

More details on this IBM article:
"**[Continuous integration with IBM Rational ClearCase Remote Client](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/continuousintegrationrationalclearcaseremoteclient/)**"

[image: CI infrastructure]

In this general architecture schema for CI with CCRC, my suggestion above (`rcleartool update`) is illustrated by the link between the CM server and the build server.

Comment: If you like an answer, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark. This will also close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd start by not re-inventing the wheel.

Team City is one such product that can do what you're asking about

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Comment: Actually, i don't want to use team city. Any other resolution??

Comment: Team city does support Clear Case though. Also, I gave Team City as an example saying "one such product is...".

Comment: Still -1. No "such product" would work in the OP's setup (CCRC, which is quite different from ClearCase).